# How do I use the DataTables Bootstrap integration in Angular2?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables, definitelytyped

I need the nice looking Bootstrap pagination control in Angular2. I can get the raw DataTables control which works fine but I need the Bootstrap look and feel. I've already integrated the core Bootstrap library and set reference paths as follows:

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../typings/jquery.dataTables/jquery.dataTables.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../typings/jquery.simplemodal/jquery.simplemodal.d.ts" />
```

I've copied the usual integration resources into my index.html file as follows but it makes no difference. Is there something else I need to do?

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SimpleApp</title>
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">


    <!-- DataTables Bootstrap integration - Should provide nice pagination control -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <parameterTable>Loading the parameter table...</parameterTable>
    </div>
</body>
```